How to parse IP addresses with System.Net.IPAddress in Azure APIM policies
I am trying to parse IP addresses with policies using the System.Net.IPAddress class in Azure APIM.
Policy:
<set-variable name="rawIpWhiteList" value="@{             
List<string> rawIpWhiteList = new List<string>(){                     
   "42.45.156.15",                     
   "177.136.25.113",                     
   "92.61.77.167",                     
   "80.254.169.123",                 
   };             
return new JArray(rawIpWhiteList);         
}" /> 
        
<set-variable name="validSingleIPs" value="@{             
   List<string> rawIpWhiteList = ((JArray)context.Variables["rawIpWhiteList"]).ToObject<List<string>>();             
   List<string> validIpWhiteList = rawIpWhiteList.Where(ipString => IPAddress.TryParse(ipString, out IPAddress _)).ToList();             
   return new JArray(validIpWhiteList);         
}" />

However, I am getting the following error:
Error: One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Error: "ValidationError" - "Error in element 'set-variable' on line 26, column 4: The name 'IPAddress' does not exist in the current context" 

Error: Error: "ValidationError" - "Error in element 'set-variable' on line 26, column 4: The name 'IPAddress' does not exist in the current context" 

But according to the policy expressions docs, the System.Net.IPAddress type should be allowed in policy expressions with the following supported members: AddressFamily, Equals, GetAddressBytes, IsLoopback, Parse, TryParse, ToString.
What am I missing?

I have modified your policy as below. please use it, you will get the result too.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="rawIpWhiteList" value="@{             
            List<string> rawIpWhiteList = new List<string>(){                     
                                  "**.**.**.***",                     
                                  "**.**.**.***",                 
                                  };             
        return new JArray(rawIpWhiteList);         
        }" />
        <set-variable name="validSingleIPs" value="@{             
            List<string> rawIpWhiteList = ((JArray)context.Variables["rawIpWhiteList"]).ToObject<List<string>>();             
            List<string> validIpWhiteList = rawIpWhiteList.Where(ipString => System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ipString, out System.Net.IPAddress _)).ToList();             
        return new JArray(validIpWhiteList);         
        }" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Output-


